# Xcode - iPhone only, Validation complaining of iPad icon issues and iTunes Connect complaining of iPad screenshots

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, app-store-connect

I am trying to submit an app to the iTunes App Store.  The app is built in Cordova/Phonegap and is for **iPhone only**.

In Xcode I clean and then archive.  From Organizer I then Validate the archive.  The validation complains of screenshots for iPad not being present, but it will let me continue.

I then submit my app using Application Loader.  It then shows me the same warnings but does allow it to be submitted.  After this point iTunes Connect then rejects my binary with the error:

```
Missing Localized Screenshots
  UK English
```

[image: Missing Screenshots]

Further investigation and it seems to be caused by missing iPad screenshots, which shouldn't be an issue given that this is an iPhone only app.

Within Xcode I have 2 project settings, one for the project itself and an inner one for the Cordova project.  Both have `Targeted Device Family` to `iPhone` for both Debug and Release.

It might be worth noting that this is an update to the app, and not a new app, so it's even more odd that it is now complaining of these issues.  It should also mean that the other info in iTunes Connect is correct.

I already have 5 screenshots for each size, but the new binary has now added 'iPad Screenshots' area, as you'll see in the screenshot below.

[image: iPad Screenshots Needed]

I'm pulling my hair out here, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this status show as "Missing Screenshot" in `RED` color?

Comment: Yep, it's red and not ready for review.  I've added a screenshot to show you in more detail

Answer (score 1):

This error doesn't seem to be missing iPad screenshot. I think, You have update screenshot either for `only below iPhone 4s` or `above iPhone5`. That will be issue. You have to update screenshot for both devices`(at least one in both).`

**Note:** There is no need to upload new binary, just update with missing screenshot in your itunes account which will make your binary to change status as "Waiting for review".

see [About App Statuses](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH30-SW1) in apple docs.

Comment: I already have 5 screenshots for each side, as this is an update rather than a new app, so they were here from the previous version.  I've updated the question with a screenshot